# ADF eroor while trying to get the output messages

Tags: error-handling, azure-data-factory

While executing i got the below error.

```
Error
{
    "errorCode": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Activity parent-control-sp failed: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '\"' is found at position 0.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Execute parent Pipeline"
}
```

I want the below message to be displayed in error table

> Activity parent-control-sp failed: JSON text is not properly
>   formatted. Unexpected character '\"' is found at position 0.",
>   "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Execute parent Pipeline" }

I have used `@{activity('Activity parent-control-sp').error.message}`. It is displaying the below message

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '\"' is
>   found at position 0.", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Execute
>   parent Pipeline" }

How to get the upper message?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to use the Execute Pipeline activity and at this point the intend to to catch any error from the child activity . I think the below expression should help you

@concat(activity('Pipeline1').error.message,'failureType:',activity('Pipeline1').error.failureType)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is not a JSON message, so you cannot use the expression (`@{activity('Activity parent-control-sp').error.message}`) to get what you want

```json
Error  <<== Remove this firstly!!!
{
    "errorCode": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Activity parent-control-sp failed: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '\"' is found at position 0.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Execute parent Pipeline"
}
```

This code will get the substring of an Error message, and then you can use an expression.

```sh
# the substring
@json(substring(
activity('xxx').error.message,
indexof(activity('xxx').error.message,'{'),
add(sub(lastindexof(activity('xxx').error.message,'}'),indexof(activity('xxx').error.message,'{')),1)
))
# get what you want
.message
```